# Bivariate GARCH model to obtain dynamic optimal hedge ratio - R

Tags: r, time-series, garch, finance

The optimal hedge ratio is the ratio of the covariance between the futures and spot price, to the variance of the future price. I estimated it already as the slope coefficient of an OLS regression of spot prices on futures prices. But it is static and I want to see its evolution.
Some authors tried modeling a bivariate GARCH (1,1) model, and that's what I am trying to do, using R.
I have no idea how to do it (using R), and what GARCH parameters would be the estimates of the optimal hedge ratio.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define and estimate a bivariate GARCH model. Extract fitted (for in-sample analysis) or predicted (for out-of-sample analysis) conditional variances $\{\hat\sigma_{x,t}^2\}$ and covariances $\{\hat\sigma_{xy,t}\}$. The minimum-variance hedge ratio at time $t$ will be $\frac{ \hat\sigma_{xy,t} }{ \hat\sigma_{x,t}^2 }$. (Parameters of the GARCH model are not directly needed for obtaining the hedge ratio.)

How to do it in R? Try the `rmgarch` package for building and fitting multivariate GARCH models. See its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf). The author's [website](http://www.unstarched.net/r-examples/rmgarch/) contains some examples, too. (If you do not like `rmgarch`, there are several other packages by other authors for fitting multivariate GARCH models.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried 
`library(rmgarch)

uspec = multispec( replicate(2, ugarchspec()) )


spec = cgarchspec(uspec, dccOrder = c(1,1))

model<-cgarchfit(spec,Ret)

#conditional covariance
rcov(model)` and it returns a matrix for each date. Should I transform the matrices to a data frame and compute the ratio from that data frame for each point ?

Comment: Also, how do I know if it is significant? For the OLS, it was straigtforward, I only had to check if the slope parameter was significant. But for the GARCH, what should I check? Thanks again for your time and your replies, it's really helpful!

Comment: @Narjems, what exactly do you want to check for significance? Regarding matrices and data frames, it is a technical question specific to R and thus not really on topic here. But AFAIK you can compute the hedge ratios directly from the matrices and then using a `for` loop, save them into a vector. There are other ways to obtain the same result, though.

Comment: I want to see if the optimal hedging ratio is significant. For the OLS, many papers check that the slope is significant, but for the GARCH, I don't know how to make sure the optimal hedging ratios are significant.

Comment: @Narjems, the notion of significance of a hedge ratio does not make sense by itself. People typically seek to evaluate significance of the difference between a quantity of interest and some benchmark value such as 0. In the case of OLS and minimum-variance hedge ratio, it is easy to do. In the case of multivariate GARCH it is harder, and I am not sure how to do that...

Comment: To me, if the ratio is not significant, then cross hedging is not possible between two commodities is not possible. But thanks again for your help, I managed to compute the Optimal hedge ratios using the rmgarch package. I'll see how to interpret all these results.

Comment: @Narjems, what you have in mind might well make a lot of sense. However, I only saw what you actually wrote and made a comment about precisely that. I am glad you have found my answer helpful :)